# Is it possible to remove some of the recipients from reminder message in SurveyMonkey, with API?

Tags: api, surveymonkey

I have created a reminder message for recipients who have not responded yet with:

```
    POST /collectors/<collector_id>/messages
{
    "type": "reminder",
    "recipient_status": "has_not_responded",
    "subject": "Reminder! We want your opinion"
}
```

It created a reminder message for all the recipients in given collector, is it possible to remove some of the recipients from this reminder message? ( with v3 API ) , they are providing an option to remove up to 1000 recipients from a reminder message in a collector in the website but I couldn't find how it could be done through API

Comment: view this thread https://www.facebook.com/surveymonkey/posts/10153252489077628

Answer (score 0):

Currently that's not possible to delete recipients from a collector after its been added (I'm not sure if that's possible in the user interface either, recipients are tied to the associated respondent/response).

When sending out a message with type `reminder` it will send out to everyone who hasn't answered the survey.

As a workaround, the only thing I can think of is to pull your recipients from the API `GET /v3/collectors/{collector_id}/messages/{message_id}/recipients` and filter out the ones you want and send them a new message with the content of the email that you want.

Comment: that's what I did.

Comment: and it is possible to edit recipients list for reminder message https://www.facebook.com/surveymonkey/posts/10153252489077628 check this thread